# unable to upload app on itunes because of CTMessageCenter?

Tags: iphone, ios5, sms, message, scheduling

I used this code in my app in order to send background sms 
But i am not able to upload app on itunes it says:using non public api
@class CTMessageCenter;

can any one tell me any way to send schedule sms when application is in background
or 
can any one tell me any way to send sms without presenting SMS composer

Comment: @FreelancerIPhoneDevelop Hi, I am searching the web for days now, how to send SMS/iMessages in the background, but I cant solfe my problem. Can you please help me to get rid of this ugly Apple composer. Visit my question and help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743804/send-imessages-without-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Comment: You can't do that the only way is the use a webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "legal" (aka permitted by Apple) way to do this.

The only work around I can assume is having a webservice on a server side, which would be the one sending the messages. You're app should communicate with the server and tell him what to do (text, hour...)

Answer (score 0):

You cant :) why would apple let you send sms on peoples behalf?

Comment: Plenty of good reasons for that, as long as the user accepts it.

Comment: But any such system is hugely open to abuse and therefore wouldnt be implemented.

Comment: Many successful apps on Android that sends sms without the user writing them. For instance where is my droid.

Comment: And so it is up to the users to decide if they trust the application.

Comment: but i know lots of developer can send message without presenting sms composer i just want to know How? and i dont want to send message on people behalf infect in my application user will scheduled message and number and time to send that message

Comment: But on IOS there is no declaration upon install of what services the app can access, so that trust barrier isnt there. @FreelanceIPhoneDeveloper Can you name an app that does this? Its probably through a web service as commented above.