# Send imessages without MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I like make my own iMessages message app. The app is basically ready but I dont know how to send iMessages without showing the MFMessageComposeViewController. I know that there is a way. They are using it in ByteSMS and all the other Message.app alternatives.

So is there a way to do so?

Thanks for any answer!

It shouldn't be submited to the Appstore. The app should be submited to Cydia or other 3rd party Stores.

Comment: Just a word of advice, that you might get rejected under the terms of being too similar to included functionality. I know that there are other apps already that do similar but I don't think you'll be able to replicate iMessage. I'm not posting this as an answer as I'm not totally sure but I think whether a message is an SMS or an iMessage is determined by the phone on whether the device is connected to 3G or better AND the recipient is an iCloud member. I don't think you can send a message specifically as an iMessage, just as a message then OS makes the decision.

Comment: @MightyLeader The app is for Cydia, not for the AppStore

Answer (score 2):

you can't do this
I tired to send message in background using CTmessageCenter it works for me but apple rejected my app due to using Private Framework (CTmessagecenter)

So if you want to do this and wants to upload app on appstore the only way is to do use 3rd party webservice

if you dont want to upload appstore then you can use CTmessagecenter that will surely works for you

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTMessageCenter.h> 

[[CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter] sendSMSWithText:@"Your Message here" serviceCenter:nil toAddress:@"Receiver's Phone Number here"];
```

here is another post may be this is what you are looking for
[Send sms using core telophony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281837/send-sms-using-core-telophony)