# Connecting to iMessage functionality with iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I am making an iPhone app and need to be able to minimally see when a message comes in, when I myself look at it, and when I answer it. I need to see when this happens on the message app that is within the iPhone iOS. I have been looking around for a solution on this and have not been able to find one.

Is this possible to access this data on the iPhone or is it completely closed off?

Comment: You have to remember that Apple is big on protecting user privacy.  So you will not find any public API where third-party accessing user private information.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Messages SDK available currently (as of iOS 8.1) that would allow a developer to interact with (or receive) messages.

The most you can do is to share content through [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/).

**Be aware** other search results suggesting you can use CoreTelephony - you app [will be rejected by Apple because CT is a private framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743804/send-imessages-without-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller).